# Windows XP mode sticks on "Checking for the latest updates for your computer" forever

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, windows-xp-mode

I have just installed Windows XP mode in Windows 7 Pro.  When I try to update it it just sits looking for updates.  I've left it there for at least two hours with no change.

I have tried everything here - http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_other-windows_update/windows-update-hangs-when-searching-for-current/f680b16d-1dee-4054-8d44-a05ace0c0fff

I have tried using the update site again using IE8.

It just stays on 'Checking for the latest updates for your computer' indefinitely.

Is updating the OS supposed to work in XP Mode?

Comment: Is it joined to a domain?  What does the WindowsUpdate.txt log say?  You can find it `\windows\windowsupdate.txt`.

Comment: Did you try the FixIt package from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/822798 at all?

Comment: What Service Pack do you have installed?

Comment: The general fix is to stop the *Windows Update* service, then delete the folder `\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\DataStore`, then start the service and try again. It will still take a while for Windows to re-scan everything to determine exactly what needs to be updated, but it *should* fix it; at least it *used to* do the trick.

Comment: @MrVimes Did the [answer by ancalimon](https://superuser.com/a/697330/272824) solve the problem? The Community bot wants to promote this question in the hope that someone will supply an answer that you accept...

Comment: @AndrewMorton I honestly have no idea/can't remember. It was such a long time ago.  At a guess I'd say it didn't if I didn't accept it.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40390

Does installing this before running WindowsUpdate on Internet Explorer 8 work?

If not uninstall XPMode and reinstall it without being connected to Internet.

Choose Do not do automatic updates

Next install this:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40612

Than reconnect to Internet and try updating.

Comment: What is "this" and "this"? When you suggest to install something, you should add some details as to what it is. Link only stuff is, well, not a preferred method here. Give some detail.

Comment: This question was asked before the fix to the problem described in the question was released.  This answer isn't really all that helpful.